# How to set the Android Live Wallpaper icon (aka "thumbnail")

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I built my first Android app.

It is a Live Wallpaper designed for 2.2.

When I press and hold the screen, select `Wallpapers` and then select `Live Wallpapers`, my live wallpaper has what looks like a default icon with the name of my live wallpaper overlaid.

How do I set this icon?

My manifest file has an application icon specified as `@drawable/icon`

Update

I think I need to add some info to this question as it poorly describes my problem (sorry).

1. I have all the `res/drawable-[hml]dpi/` icons. I named them all `icon.png`.
2. My manifest file contains `<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">`
3. I have also tried creating a 48x48 icon in `res/drawable/` called `icon.png`.
4. I have also tried explicitly adding icons in other manifest tags if they are allowed. eg. service, activity, intent-filter (It should be obvious that I don't know how this manifest file really works, so I was trying anything)
5. In `Manage Applications`, the icon **is displayed correctly**.
6. When selecting the Live Wallpaper, the icon is **not displayed correctly**.
7. `mdpi` icon is 48x48, `ldpi` icon is 36x36 and `hdpi` icon is 72x72

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In order to see an icon in the live wallpaper menu, you need to set the `android:thumbnail` attribute for the applications `<Wallpaper>` tag. This will normally be found in the XML file corresponding to the class that extends `WallpaperService`.

Looking at the `CubeLiveWallpaper` sample application provided with the SDK, we see this tag to be located in cube1.xml and cube2.xml. A modified version below displays the icon thumb.png located in `res/drawable` and provides a description defined in strings.xml

```
<wallpaper 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:thumbnail="@drawable/thumb"
    android:description="@string/description"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings"
/>
```

NOTE: this works regardless of file extension, assuming that the format is a supported type - jpg. png etc

Comment: Interesting. My SDK example doesn't match yours. I wonder if I killed it as I was trying to get Eclipse working - I picked this exact example to try first. I also don't have a thumb icon.

Comment: Thank you. I needed the thumbnail attribute and an icon. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks George. I have been using my live wallpaper for nearly a year. Works great. Thank you everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change @drawable/icon to @drawable/`<youricon>`

Comment: Is icon the default or does android use the first icon it finds?

Comment: icon is just the name of the file in res/drawable/.

Comment: I just realized SO didn't like my custom pseudo-tag. You can just name it anything you want, and it will match youricon with the name of the drawable in the res/drwable folders. It ignores the filetype so you don't need to include an extension in your xml

Comment: @Falmarri : how we can set live wallpaper as an default wallpaper from application?..have any idea?

Comment: @Subh: This question is 2 years old, you should ask a new one. But I'm pretty sure there's no way to set a "live wallpaper" as a background for an individual app. Only the system background.

Comment: @Falmarri thanks for your view..can u suggest any reference regards it?

Answer (score 1):

I've set `<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"/>` in my AndroidManifest.xml and it's working fine for each icon.png I'm using in the

/res/drawable- :== hdpi | ldpi | mdpi

folders.

Answer (score 0):

Create your icon and save it in `res/drawable/icon.png`.  You can also use `icon.jpg`, `icon.gif`, or `icon.bmp`.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have an icon.png in res/drawable.

Answer (score 0):

inside the res/drawables directories you will see icon.png. you change this file to be the icon you want. the hdpi are for the devices with high density, like the nexus one, or evo. mdpi is for devices like the myTouch or G1

Comment: I have an icon in res/drawable called icon.png. This works when the application is installed, but not when the user selects the live wallpaper. But are you suggesting that I should have different sized icon.png files in res/drawable-Xdpi/ directories?

Comment: Actually, I already have different sized icon files names icon.png in the drawable- ldpi, mdpi and hdpi directories.

Answer (score 0):

More info about resolution can be found in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/977be60a1cdf0147).

This section especially:

> ...The resolution used seems to be a lot larger than the launcher icon
>   resolution, using 48 for medium or 72 for high gives a very blurred 
>   image on both the emulator and real devices, leading me to think there
>   is some scaling going on...

Answer (score 0):

Animated .GIF file is not supported as Application launcher icon. Gif icon wont give you any compluation error but animation wont work.