# Live Wallpaper Icon Design Guideline

Tags: icons, live-wallpaper

The Android Icon Design Guidelines seem to address launcer, menu, tab, dialog .., icons. However the guidelines does not mention wallpaper icons. Is it safe to assume the launcher guidelines apply to live wallpaper icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, no.  You need to make a "thumbnail" for your wallpaper.  Looky here, fr'instance: [How to set the Android Live Wallpaper icon (aka "thumbnail")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514418/how-to-set-the-android-live-wallpaper-icon)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer...sometimes it's hard to know whether or not to "bother" answering very old questions.  I guess sometimes it is. :-)  Thanks again, and good luck.